# RELAX NG on Windows

Tags: relaxng

I am guessing that my problems could stem from Windows file issues related to UTF8. But then again, the code is Java based, so the problem could be anything.

I ran the MSV and JING validators and both gave the same result as in below. But the same file in  does validate just fine on it's internal validator. What am I missing? Note it fails on the first character, so the parser is not likely the problem. Tried running it in administrator mode to eliminate any possible permissions issues. Same result.

```
C:\docbook\src>java -jar c:\msv\msv.jar c:\docbook\rnc\docbook.rnc dgsample.xml
-debug
start parsing a grammar.
Content is not allowed in prolog.
  1:1@file:///c:/docbook/rnc/docbook.rnc
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.msv.driver.textui.Driver.run(Driver.java:221)
        at com.sun.msv.driver.textui.Driver.main(Driver.java:68)
```

Comment: The editor I was using is oXygen.

Comment: Tried with the 5 JRE, and 6 JRE

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't windows (well, not this particular problem)

You are trying to validation using a RelaxNG schema in compact format. oXygen handles this just fine as it uses Jing internally. MSV can't handle compact format as format as I'm aware.  If you need to do this at at the command line using MSV then use the Trang converter built into oXygen (Tools menu, Generate/Convert Schema in version 12.2) to convert your schema into the XML format.

Assuming that you are using a normal DocBook release you should have a copy of docbook.rng as well anyway so you could do (I don't know where you store jing.jar obviously):

```
C:\docbook\src>java -jar jing.jar c:\docbook\rnc\docbook.rng dgsample.xml
```

or

```
C:\docbook\src>java -jar c:\msv\msv.jar c:\docbook\rnc\docbook.rng dgsample.xml
```

On the other hand you can use Jing to do this but you need to tell it that the file is in compact format:

```
C:\docbook\src>java -jar jing.jar -c c:\docbook\rnc\docbook.rnc dgsample.xml
```

Hope that helps